# No output from remote Debian server

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

When I login to my Debian server over SSH, it "freezes": in interactive mode, I don't get the prompt, if I say `ssh server 'ls'`, nothing happens. I can, hovewer, use Bash built-ins, for example `ssh server 'su'` will reply "su: must be run from a terminal" and then the session ends. (Only the first session I tried gave me my home directory listing.)

I can also connect to other services (SMTP, IMAP, HTTP) over the network, but get no response.

When I reboot, everything works again.

This happens from time to time and I do not have physical access to the machine at the moment. What should I look for in the logs when I have the chance? Is there any way reboot the server remotely?

Thanks.

**Edit:** It turned to be a kernel panic caused by a misbehaving firmware. I will open a new thread I will answer to let others know how I fixed it. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Check for disk errors in particular. If you have no other way to control the server, e.g. IPMI or a networked PDU, you can't reboot the server if SSH etc. don't work. Having something like this is a mandatory requirement for a remote server you can't access, IMHO.

Comment: Check MTUs on the network pathway between client and server, too: the "*I can get little packets between these two endpoints but not big ones*" often indicates MTU negotiation failure.

Comment: @MadHatter Unfortunately, I cannot get *any* packets whatsoever.

Comment: You said `ssh server 'su'` worked.  That required quite a lot of (small) packets to flow.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that when `ls` worked once (for my first session), it would work again. Is this assumption incorrect? I do not think this is the case; `echo x` wouldn't work either :(.

Comment: I have no idea; test it and see.  I take your results so far to be "*until I do `ssh server 'ls'` once and thus freeze the connection, I can repeatably and successfully do `ssh server 'su'`*".  If that's not so, please update your question to be much more precise about the results of your testing.  In particular, statements like "*`echo x` wouldn't work*" have no place in a testing methodology; data are interesting and useful, and assumptions aren't.

Comment: Thank you for help, @MadHatter. The problem is hard to describe in its nature; I never get the prompt in interactive mode, *sometimes* (10 to 20 % of attempts) I get response to `ssh server 'ls'`. Unfortunately, root login is disabled over SSH, so I cannot read logs.

Comment: Hey, no worries.  Some problems are difficult to reproduce; that doesn't mean they aren't really annoying, and don't need fixing.  It's just that a precise data-gathering phase, free from assumptions, is really important in parametrising the problem ("*It is a capital mistake to theorize before one has data. Insensibly one begins to twist facts to suit theories, instead of theories to suit facts.*").  Could you comment on the reliability and repeatability of `ssh server 'su'`?

Comment: `ssh server 'su'` "works" (replies with "su: must be run from a terminal") anytime. Lately (in the past 20 minutes), this is also true for `su server 'ls'`. But, if I try ssh server -t `echo $password | su -S cat /var/log/kern.log`, nothing will return. (But I can `cat` a 200 KiB file.) I could restart the server, but want to have my hands on the physical machine this time. When I examined logs in the past (after the reboot), I could not find anything exceptional anywhere. By the way, I forgot to mention that once I was unable to reboot the server softly and had to uplug it from the mains.

Answer (score 1):

Check MTU or "Fragmented Packets" on the intermediate devices between you and the destination server.

I see this most often with poorly-configured [Sonicwall](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/) firewall devices.

Comment: I will, but how could this be solved by *server* reboot?

Comment: I have checked MTU setup using SpeedGuide TCP/IP Analyzer. As I haven't had to deal with MTUs till now, I would be grateful for your opinion: `[MSS: 1460, MTU: 1500 , TCP Window: 29312 (NOT multiple of MSS), RWIN Scaling: 7 bits (2^7=128), Unscaled RWIN: 229, 
Recommended RWINs: 64240, 128480, 256960, 513920, 1027840, BDP limit (200ms): 1172kbps (147KBytes/s), BDP limit (500ms): 469kbps (59KBytes/s), MTU Discovery: ON]`